# How to trigger an event when three keyboards are pressed at the same time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, keydown, keyevent

I'm writing code to execute a specific function when the `ctrl + shift + z` key is pressed. When I press two keys at the same time, it works fine, but when I press three keys, the event does not occur. Below is the code I wrote.

try1:

```
 document.onkeydown = function (e) { 

        if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'z') {  // It works
            undo()  // ctrl+ z
           
        }
        else if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key==='z' ) { //It doesn't work
            redo(); //ctrl + shift + z
        }
    }
```

try2:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) { // 
        var ctrl, shift,z
        console.log(e.key)
        switch (e.key) {
            case 'Control':
                ctrl = true;
                break;
            case 'Shift':
                shift = true;
                break;
            case 'Z':
                z = true;
                break;
   
            }
        if (ctrl&&shift&&z) redo()
  }
```

Neither of these will work if you're typing on three keyboards.

How to make it work when `ctrl+shift+z` is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the conditions, as the first condition is always `true` if the second is `true`, causing the code for the second condition to never execute.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === 'Z') {
        undo()
    } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'Z') {
        redo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the order as you suggested, but it doesn't work. Reversing the order and replacing the lowercase 'z' with the uppercase 'Z' works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I nice way to keep track of pressed keys is with an object:

```js
const keys = {}

function onKeyDown(e) {
    keys[e.key.toLowerCase()] = true
    doSomething()
}

function onKeyUp(e) {
    keys[e.key.toLowerCase()] = false
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)
window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp)

function doSomething() {
    console.log(keys)
    if (keys.control && keys.shift && keys.z) {
        console.log("redo!")
    } else if (keys.control && keys.z) {
        console.log("undo!")
    }
}
```